# How can i populate an arraylist by combining characters and numbers

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I want to populate an arraylist (length 138 23*6) with a for loop that combines characters with numbers basically something like this:

rows:23 (1..23)

colums:6(A,B,C,D,E,F)

1A,1B,1C,1D,1E,1F,2A...etc

```
ArrayList<String> seats =  new ArrayList<String>(138);

seatsCounter = -1;
for ( int rows = 0; rows < 23; rows++)
{
    seatsCounter++;
        for ( int column = 0; column < 6; column++)
        {
            switch (column)
            {
                    case 0:
                        seats = 
                        seatsCounter++;
            }

        }   
}
```

Comment: What exactly seems to be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate from zero to 23 in the outer loop, and zero to six in an inner loop. The first value is simply the counter of the outer loop. The second value is the letter `A` offset by the counter of the inner loop. In Java, characters are integral types (so you can add the counter to a `char`). Like,

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        String seat = String.valueOf(i + 1) + Character.toString((char) ('A' + j));
        al.add(seat);
    }
}
System.out.println(al);
```